# setOnClickListener has not been written well, it gives an error

Tags: java, android-studio, onclicklistener

I'm trying to rewrite my code from `android:onClick9" to` setOnClickListener`
since that crashes, bu I'm getting an error. **Code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button9=findViewById(R.id.button9);

    button9.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick9(View view) {
                button9.setText("OK");
                }
            }
    );
}

**ERROR**
error: <anonymous com.example.tablelayout6.MainActivity$1> is not
abstract and does not override abstract method onClick(View) 
in OnClickListener new Button.OnClickListener() {
```

**EDIT**

[image]

**EDIT 2** I have tried `button9` but still the label of button9 doesn't change and `new Button.OnClickListener()`  is shadowed.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button9=findViewById(R.id.button9);

        button9.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        TextView status=findViewById(R.id.button9);

                    button9.setText("OK");
                    }
                }


        );


        }
```

Comment: `public void onClick9(View view) {` should be `public void onClick(View view) {`

Comment: @StephenC I did what you've written , the error disappeared but the Label of the button hasn't changed upon clicking to "OK". Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass an anonymous class to method, you have to implements all of **its** abstract/interface inherited method.

In your code, you wrote new method called onClick9, and didn't override the abstract method onClick as needed, so it gives new an error.

You should rename your method or override on click separately.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the error disappeared but the Label of the button hasn't changed upon clicking to "OK". Why ? Also `new Button.OnClickListener() ` is shaded in MainAcitvity, not in bright text....

Comment: Inside onClick you are getting the button using findViewById and then using a textview object to store it's reference ... You can use the same button9 object for the same